# Html CSS reset being applied, but not honored

Tags: html, css

So this is a weird one, I'm getting a small margin at the very top of my page even though I've applied the standard CSS reset. If I open the inspector in Chrome / Firefox / or even *gasp* IE, I see that the body is reading my `margin:0` reset, but still adding a gap regardless.

Gap: [image]

Chrome Web Inspector that shows `margin:0` is being honord: 
[image]

So, the super duper weird part here is that if throw an important like `margin: 0 !important;` , the gap goes away. I've used this exact template set up many many times without issue. Hopefully someone sees something that is eluding me right now.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="/Content/css/Reset.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/css/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>



    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript">var base_url = 'http://localhost:64789/';</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <h2>Index</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**CSS**
Note: `Site.css` is an empty file at this point, as I just started this project.

```
html,body,p,div,img,h1,h2,h3,h4,li,ul,ol,dl,dd,dt,form {
   margin:0;  
   padding:0;  
   border:0;  
   border-collapse:separate;  
   border-spacing:0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    }

* {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    }

body {
    background: #f0f6e8 url(../images/gradbackground.jpg) repeat-x 0 top;
}    

#wrap {
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent url(../images/leaves.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}
```

Comment: Look at the `<h2>`, not the `<body>`.  Does it have an overriding top margin?

Comment: @ExplosionPills OMG, I can't believe I missed that. That was it. If you write your response to an answer, I'll gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The margin is on the `<h2>`, not the `<body>`.  There must be some other selector for `h2` that is adding the additional top margin.  In your own `Site.css` styles, include `margin-top: 0` for the `h2`

Comment: `bootstrap.css` was adding margin for the `h2` element. Well played bootstrap, you win this round.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is probably overriding it from another element.  Check the elements it is nested in for margin being set in main.css.